# React Router root element with param

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-redux-form

I am rewriting an ASP.NET MVC app to use React with Redux in TypeScript. For routing I am using React Router. The site uses a parameter at to the root to identify the customer's organization.

Example; *www.oursite.com/:organizationId* with deep links like 
*www.oursite.com/:organizationId/overview* or *www.oursite.com/:organizationId/account/:accountId*

I have configured React router as below

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, HistoryBase } from 'react-router';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import OverView from './components/OverView';
import Account from './components/Account';

export default <Route path='/:organizationId' component={ Layout }>
    <IndexRoute components={{ body: Home }} />
    <Route path='overview' components={{ body: OverView }} />
    <Route path='account/:accountId' components={{ body: Account }} />
</Route>;
```

This works, but any Link components on pages do not, as the root of the app/page is still /.

For example

```
<Link to={'/overview'} activeClassName='active' />
```

on the Account control links to *www.oursite.com/overview*, not *www.oursite.com/:organizationId/overview*.

Is there a way to configure the React Router to consider */:organizationId/* as the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the react router docs it looks like relative links as strings are not supported by react-router. Currently only absolute links are supported.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link

However, I think what you are looking for is params. React-router passes down params as props to every component that is connected to a route. For example in your overview component there should params prop. You should be able to do something like

`` <Link to={`/${this.props.params.organizationId}/overview`></Link> ``

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This works great! Because I'm using TypeScript I did have to add { params: { organizationId: string }} to the applicable props type declaration to gain access to this.props.params